# Jasmine async call trouble

Tags: javascript, bdd, jasmine

I am just getting started with jasmine unit testing and am running into some trouble with testing my async calls.

I have a ajax call that I am trying to test, and I tried it in the console so I know it works how I want it to. I think I am testing the same thing that I did in the console but could be wrong.

Here is the console:

```
> mg = new MandellMVC()
MandellMVC {getSessionId: function, setSessionId: function, isValidGetFunction: function, getURLPrefix: function, setURLPrefix: function…}
> mg.setUseLocalData(true);
true
> var log = new Log(73936780)
undefined
> log.setLogType('Proc')
true
> log.fetch(mg, function(){console.log('done');})
true
done
```

set local data just changes between sending an http request to an external server, or loading data from a local file.

The jasmine test code is here:

```
describe("Log Model", function() {

    var mg = new MandellMVC();
    mg.setUseLocalData(true);

    var log;

    beforeEach(function() {
        log = new Log(73936780);
    });

    describe("function fetch", function() {
         it("returns false if log type is invalid", function() {
            expect(log.fetch(mg, function(){})).toBeFalsy();
        });

        // Not sure why this needs to be here too?
        log = new Log(73936780);
        log.setLogType('Proc');

        it("should make a real ajax request", function() {
            var callback = jasmine.createSpy();
            log.fetch(mg, callback);
            waitsFor(function() {
                return callback.callCount > 0;
            });
            runs(function() {
                expect(callback).toHaveBeenCalled();
            });
        });
    });
});
```

The first test passes. But then the second one gives the error `timeout: timed out after 5000 msec waiting for something to happen`. I tried to follow a tutorial but apparently not very well.

Thank you, any help is much appreciated!

Comment: What developer tools (or firebug) says about AJAX request? Is it successful? Also, you should move `beforeEach` inside the inner `describe`, because it works just for one level (see [docs](http://pivotal.github.io/jasmine/#section-Setup_and_Teardown))

Comment: `beforeEach` and `afterEach` cascade down to nested describes just fine. See the next section in the docs you linked

Answer (score 1):

i think you are mixing up declaration of `log = new Log(73936780)`

the correct code should be

```
describe("Log Model", function() {
    var mg;
    var log;

    beforeEach(function() {
        mg = new MandellMVC();
        mg.setUseLocalData(true);

        log = new Log(73936780);
        log.setLogType('Proc');
    });

    afterEach(function() {
        delete mg;
        delete log;
    });

    describe("function fetch", function() {
        it("returns false if log type is invalid", function() {
            expect(log.fetch(mg, function(){})).toBeFalsy();
        });

        it("should make a real ajax request", function() {
            var callback = jasmine.createSpy();
            log.fetch(mg, callback);
            waitsFor(function() {
                return callback.callCount > 0;
            });
            runs(function() {
                expect(callback).toHaveBeenCalled();
            });
        });
    });
});
```

Additionally you should also check in firebug if the request is sent and response is received correctly